# SIGINT fail to interrupt a process

Tags: bash, osx

I tried to change to a directory using recursive globbing

```
$ cd /**/pubrepo
^C

^Cç


Ω
^Z
^C
^C
^C
^C
```

It takes lots of time. but I cannot interrupt the process with Ctrl + C.

Comment: Why do you want to `cd` into multiple directories?

Comment: **@Inian** he made a mistake and wants to get out of it, is all. **Sawajiri** Are you running on a physical or a virtual terminal?

Comment: It is probably not working because the shell is trying to expand every possible pathname on the whole system. I'm thinking that the shell is in an uninterruptible sleep state while waiting for disk.

Comment: Note: it works for me, but I may have a newer kernel, or some other difference in OS. You may just have to wait. You could start a 2nd terminal to use while waiting.